# onchange method not triggered

Tags: javascript, ajax

```html
    <html>
     <head>
      <script>
       function showUser(str) {
       if (str == "") {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
         return;
       } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form>
     <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
     <option value="">Select a person:</option>
     <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
     <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
     <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
     <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
     </select>
    </form>
     <br>
     <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The page shows the dropdown list. However, it seems the onchange method is not triggered. I don't get any return from the php. The php code is here.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: It's being triggered in the snippet here.

Comment: What does `getuser.php` do? `getuser.php?q=3` gives a response?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: The code you've posted here looks fine. The problem is probably somewhere else in your configuration.

Comment: get user.php returns a table. Here is the working sample https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_ajax_mysql

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working for me. Are you running this html file off your local machine? What I mean is that when you are loading this html file on your browser, does the address bar read `file://<path_to_html>` or `http(s)://<path_to_html>`?

If it is the former, then you need to provide the full path to the server that's hosting the `getuser.php`.

When I tried your code (running the html off my local machine), the `onchange` event was being triggered and the `xmlhttp` object was being created but no http request was being sent to the server (as per what I saw on by browser's dev tools). Then I realized I had to change the location of the `getuser.php` because it needed to be hosted on a server.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I run it on my freeshell server. http://maxfan.freeshells.org/showuser.html  This is the working sample. https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_ajax_mysql

Comment: @CCNA Your server is disallowing the request. The response is a 403. Look at your configuration for why that is.

Comment: I am getting a http 403 from the server that is hosting the `getuser.php`. It seems there is something wrong with the server config. 
https://imgur.com/a/6S7tQzO

Comment: @user3783243 you're right. I opened the console and can see the "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" What can I do?